# While loop in Kotlin Programming Language

Tags: while-loop, kotlin, kotlin-extension

In my kotlin code i am getting Type mismatch(inferred type is Int but Boolean was expected) error.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   var i = args.size 
   while (i--){
    println(args[i])
   }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear? while expects a boolean expression. i-- is of type Int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide a Boolean value as the argument of `while`. There's no auto-casting of `Int` to `Boolean` in Kotlin.

So you can't do `while(i--)`, but you can, for example, do `while(i-- != 0)` or `while(i-- > 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

**[Kotlin while loops manual](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#while-loops)**

> ```
> while (x > 0) {
>     x--
> }
>
> do {
>     val y = retrieveData()
> } while (y != null) // y is visible here!
> ```

Answer (score 1):

while expects a boolean (true/false), you give an integer (i-1). correct code could be:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   var i = args.size 
   while (i>=0){
    println(args[i])
    i--
   }
}
```